# Unir dos registros de un Array de datos

Tags: javascript, json, array

Lo que deseo es buscar la forma para poder unir dos registros iguales de un Array. Les muestro el ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y la idea es que quede de esta forma

```
[
    {
        "CodigoProcedimiento": "931000",
        "NombreProcedimiento": "TERAPIA FISICA INTEGRAL SOD    (198) (295)",
        "Cantidad": 2
    },
    {
        "CodigoProcedimiento": "939402",
        "NombreProcedimiento": "B    (266)",
        "Cantidad": 1
    },
    {
        "CodigoProcedimiento": "939400",
        "NombreProcedimiento": "TERAPIA RESPIRATORIA INTEGRAL SOD    (198) (298)",
        "Cantidad": 1
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Encontré la solución para la gente que lo necesite en un futuro.

```
const procedimientosAgrupados = [];
const procedimientos = [
    {
        CodigoProcedimiento: "931000",
        NombreProcedimiento: "TERAPIA FISICA INTEGRAL SOD    (198) (295)"
    },
    {
        CodigoProcedimiento: "931000",
        NombreProcedimiento: "TERAPIA FISICA INTEGRAL SOD    (198) (295)"
    },
    {
        CodigoProcedimiento: "939402",
        NombreProcedimiento: "B    (266)"
    },
    {
        CodigoProcedimiento: "939400",
        NombreProcedimiento: "TERAPIA RESPIRATORIA INTEGRAL SOD    (198) (298)"
    }
]


procedimientos.forEach(procedimiento => {
    if (!procedimientosAgrupados.find(procedimientoBuscado => procedimientoBuscado.CodigoProcedimiento == procedimiento.CodigoProcedimiento)) {
        const { CodigoProcedimiento, NombreProcedimiento } = procedimiento;
        var Cantidad = 1;
        procedimientosAgrupados.push({ CodigoProcedimiento, NombreProcedimiento, Cantidad });
    }else{
        var index = procedimientosAgrupados.findIndex(procedimientoBuscado => procedimientoBuscado.CodigoProcedimiento == procedimiento.CodigoProcedimiento);
        procedimientosAgrupados[index].Cantidad =  procedimientosAgrupados[index].Cantidad +1;
    }
});

console.log(procedimientosAgrupados);
```